# Why static and dynamic variable are not able allocated during initialization in c

Tags: c

1)invalid scenario

```
int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(p));

int main(void)
{

    *p = 10;
    printf("%d", *p);
}
```

2) invalid scenario

```
int main(void){

   static int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(p));

}
```

3) //valid scenario

```
int main(void){

   static int *p;
   p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(p));

}
```

4) valid scenario

```
int *p;

int main(void)
{

     p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(p));
    *p = 10;
    printf("%d", *p);
}
```

why Scenario 1 and 2 are invalid and Scenario 3 and 4 are valid?

Comment: Invalid? In what terms, memory leaks?

Comment: compilation error is coming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, the only real answers boil down to simply "those are the rules".  C *could* have been specified differently, so that the usages you are asking about were all valid, but it was not.

Perhaps you're asking about rationale.  Certainly C's chosen approach is simpler, as it allows all objects of static duration (including all globals and `static` locals) to be initialized from data stored in the program image.  Allowing initializers that are not compile-time constants would require program execution to begin in the initializers, before `main()` is called.  That would be both more complex and messier.